# Can't center my html input areas

Tags: html, css

So, not sure why this isn't working I am trying to center some input boxes and I checked some other stack overflow threads, tried the solutions and still can't seem to get it to work.. please help! Here's how I have it right now (style on the input tags)

```
<!-- Register Form -->
<div class="user_register" >
   <form>
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <br></br>
            <tr>
               <td><input type="text" name ='first_name' size='8 placeholder='First Name'/></td>
               <td><input id ='last_name'type="text" name = 'last_name' size='8' placeholder ='Last Name'/></td>
            </tr>
            <br></br>
            <tr>
               <td><input style="margin:0px auto; display:block;" class='register_inputs' type="text" name='username' placeholder='Username' size='14'/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><input style="margin:0px auto; display:block;"  class='register_inputs' type="text" name='email' placeholder='Email'size='14' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><input style="margin:0px auto; display:block;"  style="margin:0px auto; display:block;" class='register_inputs' type="password" name='password' placeholder='Password' size='14' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><input style="margin:0px auto; display:block;"  class='register_inputs' type="password" name='confirm_password' placeholder='Confirm Password' size='14' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><a href="#"        class="submit_reg">Register</a></td>
               <td><a href="#" class="back_to_login">Back</a></td>
            </tr>
      </table>
   </form>
</div>
```

I've also tried style in the div like so:

```
 <div style="text-align:center;">
    <input type="text" />
 </div>
```

and using a class/id on the inputs and surrounding div to style with css. Nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: text-align centers text within the element.  I believe that you are trying to center the element within another element.   That would require the property align:center on the input element.  See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Comment: you just need to add margin  : 0 auto; on the table and it will be centered, check my answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `table { margin : 0 auto }` on your css and it will be centered

I added your code to demonstrate what I mean :)

```css
table { margin : 0 auto; }
```

```html
<div class="user_register" >
                            <form>
                            <table>
                            <tbody>
                    <br></br>


                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="text" name ='first_name' size='8 placeholder='First Name'/></td>
                                 <td><input id ='last_name'type="text" name = 'last_name' size='8' placeholder ='Last Name'/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <br></br>


                            <tr>
                                <td><input style="margin:0px auto; display:block;" class='register_inputs' type="text" name='username' placeholder='Username' size='14'/></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td><input style="margin:0px auto; display:block;"  class='register_inputs' type="text" name='email' placeholder='Email'size='14' /></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td><input style="margin:0px auto; display:block;"  style="margin:0px auto; display:block;" class='register_inputs' type="password" name='password' placeholder='Password' size='14' /></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>    
                                <td><input style="margin:0px auto; display:block;"  class='register_inputs' type="password" name='confirm_password' placeholder='Confirm Password' size='14' /></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="#"        class="submit_reg">Register</a></td>
                                <td><a href="#" class="back_to_login">Back</a></td>
                            </tr>   
                        </table>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

On the code below I added `colspan="2"` on rows that have single column so it matches your rows with 2 columns. I also set `width: 100%` to your input textbox and password  so that they matches the width of its parent `td`

```css
table { margin : 0 auto; }
td { padding : 0px 2px; }

input[type="text"], 
input[type="password"] {
 width : 100%;
}

a.back_to_login {
  text-align : right;
  display : block;
}
```

```html
<div class="user_register" >
    <form>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name ='first_name' size='8 placeholder='First Name'/></td>
                     <td><input id ='last_name'type="text" name = 'last_name' size='8' placeholder ='Last Name'/></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input style="margin:0px auto; display:block;" class='register_inputs' type="text" name='username' placeholder='Username' size='14'/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input style="margin:0px auto; display:block;"  class='register_inputs' type="text" name='email' placeholder='Email'size='14' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input style="margin:0px auto; display:block;"  style="margin:0px auto; display:block;" class='register_inputs' type="password" name='password' placeholder='Password' size='14' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>    
                    <td colspan="2"><input style="margin:0px auto; display:block;"  class='register_inputs' type="password" name='confirm_password' placeholder='Confirm Password' size='14' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#" class="submit_reg">Register</a></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="back_to_login">Back</a></td>
                </tr>   
         </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the easiest way. Though based on your example (and if I remove the css for absolute position on the top 2 boxes) it still puts the inputs on the left for some reason .. But at least works for what I have right now.

Comment: don't use absolute position because it will ignore the rules you set on its parent. If you have rows that have 2 columns and others have one column  set the td colspan="2" on single column, I will update my answer to show you what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Add this to make it center `div { display: table; margin: 0 auto; }` but it supports major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox features:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

div > * {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 6px auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="radio" />
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <select>
    <option value="">Option</option>
  </select>
<div>
```